# How to disable a whole div?

Tags: html

I have a div and inside it form elements such a radio buttons or checkboxes. I want to enable/disable all the same in one fell swoop. This

```
<!-- 1 -->
<div disabled="true">
  ........
</div>

<!-- or -->  
<!-- 2 -->
<div disabled="disabled">
  ........
</div>
```

doesn't work. How to make it work without having to disable each individual html form element in a div?

Comment: `enable/disable` or `show/hide` because there is no such thing as `enable/disable` for `div`?

Comment: Use JavaScript to disable the individual form elements.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over all form elements inside your div and disable them one by one like this:

```js
// Helper function to change disabled state of single element
function changeDisabledState( elm, disabled ) {
  if ( !disabled ) {
    elm.removeAttribute( 'disabled' );
  }
  else {
    elm.setAttribute( 'disabled', disabled );
  }
}

function toggleFormDiv( container ) {
  // Check if helper class is there
  const isDisabled = container.classList.contains( 'disabled' );

  // Query all fields inside DIV.
  const allFields = container.querySelectorAll( 'input, textarea, button, select' );
  
  // Iterate over all elements and set the opposite state
  [ ...allFields ].forEach( elm => {
    changeDisabledState( elm, !isDisabled );
  } );
  
  // Toggle helper class
  container.classList.toggle( 'disabled' );
}

document.getElementById( 'toggle' ).addEventListener( 'click', () => {
  // Get DIV container to be disabled
  const container = document.querySelector( '.container' );
  toggleFormDiv( container );
} );
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="container">
    <input type="input" value="Textfield" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <button>Button</button>
    <select>
      <option>Select</option>
    </select>
    <textarea>Textarea</textarea>
  </div>
</form>

<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using JQuery. To disable all controls you need to set the disabled attribute value to disabled using jquery attr() method based on [this demo](http://dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/239/Disabel-or-Enable-all-controls-in-a-div-using-jquery.aspx).

//To disable elements of div1

```
$("#div1").find("input, button, submit, textarea, select").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no such as disabling a Div in HTML in fact you can use JQuery for example to disable all the content of this DIV using foreach loop . As for CSS rules you have to define them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can see answer in **PHP** `if` and `else` statement, which can "disable" part of code :)

```
<?php

if(smthing) {
echo <<<END
<div> ... </div>
END;
} 

else {
echo <<<END
<div> ... </div>
END;
}
?>
```

---

**-Edit:** *This is PHP solution => Server-side solution.*

### Maybe **JQuery** or **JavaScript** helps more :))

Hope I help you :)

**EriiYenn Lacroix**

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the requirements of "How to make it work without having to disable each individual html form element in a div?" You've just shifted the work from from client side to server side.

Comment: It's still one way to do. Probably you can use logic of W3.css "hide" and "show" classes + script, when show div.